# como puedo usalor HttpPostedFileBase en asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Quiero resolver este problema para almacenar la imagen en la base de datos. Todavía no ejecuto el proyecto, si tengo errores o una forma más fácil de hacerlo ... ayuda

```
public IActionResult Create(Productos prod [Bind("codigoFoto"] Productos productos, HttpPostedFileBase FotoProducto) 
                   {

    //Console.WriteLine(JObject.FromObject(prod));
                    using (var _context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                    {
                        var Categoria = _context.Categorias.Where(i => i.IsActive && i.Id == prod.Categoria.Id).FirstOrDefault(); 
                        if (prod != null)
                        {
                            if (FotoProducto != null && FotoProducto.ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                byte[] imageData = null;

                                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(FotoProducto.InputStream))
                                {
                                    imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(FotoProducto.ContentLength);
                                }
                                //setear la imagen a la entidad que se creara
                                productos.Foto = imageData;
                            }
```

Comment: Hola Angel, sería bueno para comprender mejor el problema que agregues el código de la vista y también el mensaje de error que estás recibiendo y el momento. Es al compilar o al ejecutar?

Comment: saludos, muchas gracias puede resolver ese problema.

Comment: Genial Luis, si podes dejá la solución así otro que se tope con el mismo problema tiene idea de cómo resolverlo, gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

```
        var query = _context.Categorias.Where(i => i.IsActive).ToList();
        ViewBag.CategoriasId = new SelectList(query, "Id", "Nombre");
        if (prod != null)
        {
            if (FotoProducto != null && FotoProducto.Length > 0)
            {
                byte[] imageData = null;

                var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                var file = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                file = Path.Combine(file, FotoProducto.FileName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))

                // using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(FotoProducto.InputStream))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FotoProducto.CopyTo(stream);
                        stream.Position = 0;
                        imageData = ReadFully(stream);
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageData);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }
                    //imageData = filePath.ReadBytes(FotoProducto.Length);
                }
                //setear la imagen a la entidad que se creara
                prod.Foto = filePath;
            }
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si explicas tu solución, lee [answer]